# Changing display of the indentation line of the mixed view in the orgchart (Balkan Graph)

Tags: orgchart

Is it possible to change the way of defining the indentation lines in the Orgchart layout: BALKANGraph.mixed option according to the image?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The current version of [OrgChart JS](https://balkangraph.com/) support only two layouts: normal and mixed. The next major version of OrgChart JS will support six new layouts

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback!
Would you know of a timeline of when will the version with these features come out?

Comment: The new major version is expected after two weeks